# Stronger version of Picard's existence theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Picard's existence theorem says that equation
$$y'(x)=f(x, y(x)),~y(x_0)=y_0,$$
where $f$ has [some properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), has a unique solution. Moreover it allows one to construct an iterative approximate solution.

I wonder whether there is a result allowing one to say anything (existence, uniqueness) about equation:

$$y'(x)=f(x, y(g(x))),~y(x_0)=y_0,$$

where $g$ and $f$ are *some* functions (e.g. analytic - just continuity or Lipschitz continuity may be too weak to say anything interesting).

Comment: For instance, if you take $g(x)=x-1$ you get (an example of) [delay-differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).  For such an equation, the initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$ is way too little to have uniqueness of solutions.